# How can a C program call a Perl function?

Tags: c, perl

I am invoking a perl subroutine from my C program using `call_pv`.
I have 2 questions:

1. How will the C program find in which Perl file this subroutine is defined? Is there any place we can define the Perl file name?
2. If the Perl returns a hash reference as output, how can I read it in C?

This is my C function:

```
static int call_perl_fn(char* image)
{

dSP;
int count;
ENTER;
SAVETMPS;
PUSHMARK(SP);
XPUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVpv(image, 0))); //parameter to perl subroutine
PUTBACK;
count = call_pv("ImageInfo", G_SCALAR); //Invoking ImageInfo subroutine
SPAGAIN;
if (count != 1)
{
    printf("ERROR in call_pv");
}
printf("VALUE:%s", (char*)(SvRV(POPp))); //How to read has reference output?
PUTBACK;
FREETMPS;
LEAVE;

return count;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `argv[1]` to put the filename, so before of `perl_run(my_perl_interpreter);` do something like this:

```
char *my_argv[] = { "", "NAME_HERE.pl" };
perl_parse(my_perl_interpreter, NULL, 2, my_argv, (char **)NULL);
```

About the return value, instead of POPp you should use POPs to get an SV value, then inspect it to determine the type, with SvTYPE(), and do the correspondent processing.

Take a look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcall.html

Comment: ... and "perlapi" for documentation on the macros and functions for working with perl's C representation of the native data types such as SV*, AV*, HV*, and friends.

Answer (score 2):

1) `call_pv` doesn't find subs in files any more than `ImageInfo($image)` in Perl does. You need to create the subs as always.

2) A reference to what? For example, a reference to a string:

```
SV * rv;
SV * sv;
char * buf;
STRLEN len;

rv = POPs;
if (!SvROK(rv)) {
   ... error ...
}

sv = SvRV(rv);
buf = SvPVutf8(sv, len);  # For text. Use SvPVbyte for strings of bytes.
...
```

A reference to a hash would be more like:

```
SV * rv;
SV * sv;
HV * hv;

rv = POPs;
if (!SvROK(rv)) {
   ... error ...
}

sv = SvRV(rv);
if (SvTYPE(sv) != SVt_PVHV) {
   ... error ...
}

hv = MUTABLE_HV(sv);
... Use hv_* functions to look into the hash ...
```

[perlapi](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlapi.html)

Comment: hash reference
Updated the question.